# Strange template instantiation bug with non-type argument

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, compiler-bug

The following C++11 code compiles with g++ 4.7.4, g++ 4.8.5, g++ 4.9.3 and g++ 5.3.0, but not with clang++ 3.7.1 or clang++ 3.8.0 (trunk 254750):

```
template <typename F, F f> struct MetaValue {};

template <typename T> class IntSpec;
template <int V> class IntSpec<MetaValue<int, V> > {};

// note: template is declared here:
template <typename T> class PtrSpec;
template <void * V> class PtrSpec<MetaValue<void *, V> > {};

int main() {
  IntSpec<MetaValue<int, 0> >();

  // implicit instantiation of undefined template 'PtrSpec<MetaValue<void *, nullptr> >'
  PtrSpec<MetaValue<void *, nullptr> >();
}
```

Clang only errors on instantiation of `PtrSpec<>` but not on `IntSpec<>`. Is this a compiler bug, an ambiguity in the standard or something I always need to consider when writing code? Please provide a reference, if possible.

**EDIT:** My further analysis found that the following works for both compilers:

```
template <typename F, F f> struct MetaValue {};

// note: template is declared here:
template<typename T> class PtrSpec;
template <int * V> class PtrSpec<MetaValue<int *, V> > {};

extern int x;

int main() { PtrSpec<MetaValue<int *, &x> >(); }
```

but if I change `&x` to `nullptr` I get `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'PtrSpec<MetaValue<int *, nullptr> >'` with clang++.

Comment: File a bug with Clang.  They will want to fix this.

Comment: @Graznarak Nah, not enough motivation atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work fine, due standard. From [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

**§14.3.2/1:**

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter*
> shall be one of:
>
> [...]
>
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
>
> [...]

**§14.3.2/5:**

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a
> non-type *template-argument*. If a non-type *template-argument* cannot be
> converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter* then the
> program is ill-formed.
>
> [...]
>
> - for a non-type *template-parameter* of type pointer to object,
>   qualification conversions (4.4) and the array-to-pointer conversion
>   (4.2) are applied; if the *template-argument* is of type `std::nullptr_t`,
>   the null pointer conversion (4.10) is applied. [*Note:* [...] However, both
>   `(int*)0` and `nullptr` are valid *template-arguments* for a non-type
>   *template-parameter* of type “pointer to int.” — *end note*]
>
> [...]

Comment: Any idea why Clang fails thou?